# Convert Phone Number to E164 format in API 14

Tags: android

I am trying to format any phone number(local or international) to a standard E164 format , but methods in PhoneNumberUtils are for the most added to API levels 21 and newer, the others do not have a persistent formating ensuring a standard way that nbumbers are displayed, is there any way to achieve this , without using any library ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's open-source library [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber) to convert your phone numbers. In fact PhoneNumberUtils use the same library.

However the library will need ISO 3166-1 two letter country-code and you can use use the network language for the default country code, available using [getNetworkCountryIso](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkCountryIso%28%29).
You can use the following code:

```
PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
Phonenumber.PhoneNumber formattedNumber = null;
String formatted = null;

try {
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String countryCode = manager.getNetworkCountryIso();
    formattedNumber = phoneUtil.parse(phoneNumber, countryCode);
    formatted = phoneUtil.format(formattedNumber,PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164);

if (StringUtils.isEmpty(formatted) == false && formatted.length() > 0 && StringUtils.isEmpty(name) == false && name.length() > 0) {
        listName.add(name);
        listPhoneNumber.add(formatted);
    }
} catch (NumberParseException e) {
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Android is open source, you could just import the most recent version of `PhoneNumberUtils` yourself: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.java

Comment: Ok but do i do that, by copying the entire file and including it in my project ?I'm new to android developement , i'm using Android Studio 1.5